# Separating alphabet and numerical part from the string in python

Tags: python, nlp, python-re

I have multiple strings which contain alphabets and numerical part, I want to separate those part.

```
a='swich 125mg'

re.findall(r'[A-Za-z]+|\d+',a)
output--> ['swich','125','mg']
```

I get the required output. But when i have another string

```
a="voglikem 0.2 tablets (10's)"

a=['voglikem', '0', '2', 'tablets', '10', 's']
```

`0.2` get separated in `0` and `2` which I don't want. Can any help me in this?

Answer (score 2):

Simply add `.` to the `\d` and wrap it in `[]`

`[A-Za-z]+|[\d.]+`